# Set quota for HTML5 File API in NW.js application

Tags: javascript, html, node-webkit, nw.js

How do you set the quota for the HTML5 File API in a NW.js application?

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "main": "index.html",
  "dom_storage_quota": 1024,
  "window": {
    "width": 1024,
    "height": 600
  }
}
```

When I try to save a file using the HTML5 File API I get a `QuotaExceededError` error.

`webkitStorageInfo` indicates my quota is 0 even after setting `"dom_storage_quota": 1024`

```
window.webkitStorageInfo.queryUsageAndQuota(webkitStorageInfo.PERSISTENT, function(used, remaining) {
  console.log("Used quota: " + used + ", remaining quota: " + remaining);
}, function(e) {
  console.log('Error', e);
});
```

Used quota: 0, remaining quota: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default quota for PERSISTENT storage is 0. You need to use the requestQuota() method from the Quota Management API

```
webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota(
  webkitStorageInfo.PERSISTENT
  newQuotaInBytes,
  quotaCallback,
  errorCallback);
```